# Random redirrect after the page is loaded/clicked

Tags: asp.net, razor-2

I'm working on ASP.NET Razor v2 website, right now I have a link that helps me send the user to a random url that I have it as a list, it looks like this;

```
@{
    List<string> UrlList = new List<string>();
UrlList.Add("http://example1.com/");
UrlList.Add("http://example2.com/");
UrlList.Add("http://example3.com/");
    Random r = new Random();
    int index = r.Next(UrlList.Count);
    string randomUrl = UrlList[index];
}

<a href="@randomUrl">A Random Link</a>
```

When I hover the "A Random Link" I see one of the links in the list.

Is there a way to redirrect the user to a URL after the page is loaded?

So to put it simply; 
Click "A Random Link" -> Load another page -> Redirrect to a link from List.

Comment: you want the user to be redirected to the page even without clicking the link ?

Comment: No I want the user to be redirected after he/she clicks the link.

Comment: it should be redirected because it is an anchor tag. What behaviour are you seing ?

Comment: Its opening a random link from the list but if I click 5 times its the same link, I want it to randomize the URL's after I clicked the link, so when I click 5 times it should be 5 random URL's.

Comment: you need to reload your page and it will generate random links as anchor tag target url.

Comment: Yes it does generate after I reload, but I want it to have a link that redirects to a random URL without reloading. Sorry, I think I didnt explain my question good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to reload the target url when user clicks on this.So you should

```
<a id="aRand" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">A Random Link</a>
```

Now in your javascript, when user clicks the link, get the random number and read the link from the js array and update the clicked anchor tags href attribute.

```
$(function(){
  var itemArr=["http://a.com","http://b.com","http://c.com"];

  $("#aRand").click(function(e){

     var randomNum=getRandom(0,itemArr.length);   
     var targetUrl=itemArr[randomNum];
     $(this).attr("href",targetUrl);

  });

});

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Instead of hardcoding the array, you may get it from your server action method using an ajax request.